# Typescript: is it ok to use enum as function parameter type?

Tags: typescript, enums

Simple question, yet I have a doubt and couldn't find the answer.

Suppose you have this enum:

```
export enum fooEnum {
    Foo = 'foo',
    Bar = 'bar'
}
```

Then would it be ok to type my function parameters this way? Meaning 'I expect to receive a string 'foo' or 'bar' as parameter and expect to return 'foo' or 'bar'

```
function doStuff(myParam: FooEnum): FooEnum {
    return myParam;
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use an `enum` as parameter.

The only thing that you might want to consider (but in most cases negligible), is that an `enum` will be included in the generated `JavaScript`.

```
export enum fooEnum {
    Foo = 'foo',
    Bar = 'bar'
}
```

Will generate the following `JavaScript` code (or similar):

```
var fooEnum;
(function (fooEnum) {
    fooEnum["Foo"] = "foo";
    fooEnum["Bar"] = "bar";
})(fooEnum || (fooEnum = {}));
```

As an alternative you could use a [String Literal](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html) type, which will not be included in the generated code.

```
export type fooType = 'foo' | 'bar';
```

---

**EDIT** - Thanks to Aleksey L.

You can also define a `const enum`, which is also not included in the generated code.

```
export const enum fooEnum {
    Foo = 'foo',
    Bar = 'bar'
}
```

And when used

```
var bar = fooEnum.Bar;
```

the following code will be generated as

```
var b = 'bar';
```

**const enum VS string literal type**

With the `const enum` approach it comes down to just personal preference whether you find

```
doStuff(fooEnum.Bar);
```

or `string literal` types

```
doStuff('bar');
```

more readable. The generated result will be the same in both cases.

Comment: I like that! Thanks :)

Comment: @FlorentArlandis @Philipp If you don't want to have generated object, you can just define `const enum FooEnum...`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks, good to know. Do you know why this works that way?

Comment: This is how const enums defined in typescript spec. More info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums)

Answer (score 1):

An `enum` is just like any other type it can be used as a parameter and also used as a return type. So yes that syntax would work fine.

I do not know why you would need to pass in an `Enum` value and then return a different `Enum` value but none the less you can do what you are doing and it is correct in TypeScript.

Comment: Passing in an enum and returning a different enum might form part of a state machine implementation.